# Message Manager API sendAsyncMessage callback

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I can return a value if I send a sync message:

```
// frame script
var chromeBtnText = sendSyncMessage("getChromeToolbarButtonText");
if (chromeBtnText == 'blah') {
    alert('tool is blah');
}

// chrome script
messageManager.addMessageListener("getChromeToolbarButtonText", listener);

function listener(message) {
  return document.getElementById('myChromeToolbarButton').label.value;
}
```

How do I achieve this with a callback with `sendAsyncMessage`?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
// frame script
function myCallback(val) {
    var chromeBtnText = val;
    if (chromeBtnText == 'blah') {
        alert('tool is blah');
    }
}
var chromeBtnText = sendAsyncMessage("getChromeToolbarButtonText", null, myCallback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback for replies. In fact, there is no reply at all. The return value from the chrome message listener is simply ignored for async messages.

To do fully async communication, you'd have to send *another* message containing the reply.

Frame script

```
addMessageListener("getChromeToolbarButtonTextReply", function(message) {
  alert(message.data.btnText);
});

sendAsyncMessage("getChromeToolbarButtonText");
```

Chrome

```
messageManager.addMessageListener("getChromeToolbarButtonText", function(message) {
  var btnText = document.getElementById('myChromeToolbarButton').label.value;
  // Only send message to the frame script/message manager
  // that actually asked for it.
  message.target.messageManager.sendAsyncMessage(
    "getChromeToolbarButtonTextReply",
    {btnText: btnText}
  );
});
```

PS: All messages share a namespace. So to avoid conflicts when another piece of code wants to use the same name `getChromeToolbarButtonText`, you better choose a more unique name in the first place, like prefixing your messages with your add-on name `my-unique-addoon:getChromeToolbarButtonText` or something like that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was also hoping to do something similar:

```
messageManager.sendAsyncMessage("my-addon-framescript-message", null, myCallback);
```

I'm going the other direction so the myCallback would be in chrome but it's exactly the same principle.

I'd used similar approaches to @Noitidart and @nmaier before but in this new case I wanted to bind to some local data so myCallback can behave differently based on the application state at the time the first message was sent rather than at the time the callback is executed, all while allowing for the possibility of multiple message round-trips being in progress concurrently.

Chrome:

```
let someLocalState = { "hello": "world" };
let callbackName = "my-addon-somethingUnique"; // based on current state or maybe generate a UUID

let myCallback = function(message) {
    messageManager.removeMessageListener(callbackName, myCallback);
    //message.data.foo == "bar"
    //someLocalState.hello == "world"
}.bind(this); // .bind(this) is optional but useful if the local state is attached to the current object

messageManager.addMessageListener(callbackName, myCallback);
messageManager.sendAsyncMessage("my-addon-framescript-message", { callbackName: callbackName } );
```

Framescript:

```
let messageHandler = function(message) {
let responseData = { foo: "bar" };
    sendAsyncMessage(message.data.callbackName, responseData);
};

addMessageListener("my-addon-framescript-message", messageHandler);
```

There's a real-world example here: https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/commit/c50f99033d2d07068140438816f8cc5e5e290da9

It should be possible for Firefox to be improved to encapsulate this functionality in the built-in messageManager one day but in the mean-time this approach works well and with a surprisingly small amount of boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 0):

in this snippet below. i add the callback before `sendAsyncMessage('my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarbuttonText'...` as i know it will send back. Then I remove it after callback executes. I know I don't have to but just to kind of make it act like real callback, just to kind of show people, maybe it helps someone understand.

Frame:

```
/////// frame script
function CALLBACK_getChromeToolbarButtonText(val) {
    removeMessageListner('my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarButtonTextCallbackMessage', CALLBACK_getChromeToolbarButtonText); //remove the callback
    var chromeBtnText = val;
    if (chromeBtnText == 'blah') {
        alert('tool is blah');
    }
}

addMessageListener('my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarButtonTextCallbackMessage', CALLBACK_getChromeToolbarButtonText); //add the callback
var chromeBtnText = sendAsyncMessage("my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarButtonText", null);
```

Chrome:

```
////// chrome script
messageManager.addMessageListener("my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarButtonText", listener);

function listener() {
    var val = document.getElementById('myChromeToolbarButton').label.value;
    sendAsyncMessage('my-addon-id@jetpack:getChromeToolbarButtonTextCallbackMessage',val);
}
```